# Remove Whitespace From XML Nodes

Tags: c#, windows, xml, parsing, whitespace

How can I remove whitespace on every instance of a particular node which I specify in C#? For example let's say that I have the following XML document:

```
<XML_Doc>

  <Record_1>
     <Name>Bob</Name>
     <ID_Number>12345</ID_Number>
     <Sample>
     </Sample>
  </Record_1>

  <Record_2>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <ID_Number>54321</ID_Number>
     <Sample>
     </Sample>
  </Record_2>

</XML_Doc>
```

What I would like is to take every instance of the `<Sample>` tag and change the formatting so it looks like this:

```
<XML_Doc>

  <Record_1>
     <Name>Bob</Name>
     <ID_Number>12345</ID_Number>
     <Sample></Sample>
  </Record_1>

  <Record_2>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <ID_Number>54321</ID_Number>
     <Sample></Sample>
  </Record_2>

</XML_Doc>
```

**EDIT:**

The other application which makes use of the XML file was not written by me and I cannot modify the structure of the XML document itself. I am writing a utility which parses the XML file and replaces each instance of the node I specify. The example where the `<Sample></Sample>` tag is on the same line is how the document is originally formatted and how I need it to be for the other application to be able to read it correctly.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to just have formatted XML or if you want to preserve whitepace and other characters in the XML. Your example seems to REMOVE the whitespace, not preserve it.

Comment: You are correct, I stated things backwards.

Comment: I dont see any issue with the original xml. The application should not behave differently if the closing node is on another line vs on the same line. Is the application using this xml refusing it?

Comment: I have no idea how the other application has been coded. It has been verified that the given the way it parses this XML file, it will not parse correctly when instances of that node are not on the same line.

Comment: If you are already building a parser that replaces each instance of a specific node, then surely all you need to do is to take every instance of that node you find, in string form, and String.Replace the whitespace in it to the empty string (using a Regex)?

Comment: @Joren

Unfortunately it isn't that simple. From what I can gather, the XML file is changed into proper XML format as is the behavior of parsing with members of the XmlDocument class. I am now trying to remove that formatting since this other application which makes use of the XML file cannot interpret it when it is in proper XML format. So, I would need to do something like using something other than the XmlDocument class to parse the file and then fix the whitespace. I am still struggling to figure out what to do here.

Comment: I have discovered that the program which uses this XML file was written in C++, not C#. The program which I am writing in C# is a utility to test that main application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in preserving whitespace (ie: tabs, carriage returns and other formats) you can use the [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) (unparsed character data).

```
<![CDATA[
]]>
```

However, if you just want to have an XML document that is formatted a certain way for aesthetic purposes , I would advise you to leave it alone.

To write a CDATA section into an XML Document use the following code:

```
XmlNode itemDescription = doc.CreateElement("description");
XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection("<P>hello world</P>");
itemDescription.AppendChild(cdata);
item.AppendChild(itemDescription);
```

This produces

```
<description><![CDATA[<P>hello world</P>]]></description>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set

```
xml.Settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an xslt transform. Doing it this way allows you to have control over the  stripping or preservation of white space.

MSDN has an article that addresses this issue, see: [Controlling White Space with the DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757885(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think you *may* be able to use the [XmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx) property to change how the text node handles the carriage returns. You'll have to experiment. I suspect the receiving application has some line parsing issue and is looking for a \r\n or something.